# php image hosting sharing script

Tags: php

Anything like this exist in the open source world? I can roll my own, but im looking to save time if possible.

Looking for something that will allow users to upload files and recieve a shortened URL to share.
Possible have an api to allow other services to send pictures and return the shortened address.

Comment: StackOverflow is about building, not finding...

Comment: I appreciate your input, but i would like to avoid re-inventing the wheel if at all possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With only a little effort in google you could have found out that there exists an ImageShack API.

[Here](http://elliottback.com/wp/using-the-imageshack-xml-api/) is a tutorial which might help you getting started.

Answer (score 3):

I know of two full-blown, cool looking solutions which are open source and GPL or MIT licensed:

- [<strike>script for imagepng.com</strike>](http://thatsmith.com/2009/01/open-source-image-sharing-script) (GPL)
- [Chevereto](https://github.com/Chevereto/Chevereto-Free) (free except for (re-)distribution)

EDIT 2009-12-19: Added Chevereto.
EDIT 2015-11-22: Removed imagepng.com (gone since 2014)
EDIT 2016-10-19: Changed Chevereto link to GitHub version, updated license